# Xamarin Forms iOS call web api

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms

I have an app that I'm developing using Xamrin Forms. The Android version works flawlessly. The iOS debug version runs flawlessly. I am having a problem with the iOS release version. What is happening is that the app is calling a web API for data access. When it calls the API the call times out, doesn't get accessed denied or anything like that. I've tried adding the associated domains entitlement without any success. I think it is the apple-app-site-association file. I've uploaded it to my server in the root directory but it's not working as I'd expect. This is my file, redacted, if somebody could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

```
{
    "applinks": {
        "apps": [],
        "details": {
            "XXXXXXXX.com.maxxautomotive.TransmissionApp": {
                "paths": [
                    "/WebApi/Account/*",
                    "/WebAPi/DataAccess/*"
                ]
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: http or https?  Have you ruled out basic connectivity issues?  Are you testing from the emulator or a real device?

Comment: https. I've ruled out connectivity issues and I'm testing on the emulator

Comment: I don't know what `apple-app-site-association` would possibly have to do with it.  That should have no impact on your app making API calls.  Can you post the relevant code?

Comment: It was a  release configuration issue after all. It is working fine now. Thanks.